# pygame: from pygame.locals import * not working

Tags: python, pygame

In my code

`from pygame.locals import *`

gets the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    from pygame.locals import *
ImportError: No module named 'pygame.locals'
```

I have ensured that I don't have any files named `pygame.py` or `pygame.pyc` in my working directory and I'm using `Python3.3.5` and `pygame-1.9.2a0-hg` on Windows 10. Could there be any other reason for this error?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have pygame installed... Are you sure you've downloaded it correctly and downloaded it for Python3.x, not Python2.x?

Comment: I get no errors in the Python shell with import pygame. puzzeled

Comment: What do you mean? Can you use pygame but not globally import pygame.locals?

Comment: I have not really gotten very far as yet with pygame. I'm following a tutorial. import pygame returns no errors so I'm asuming its installed. but from pygame.locals import * returns the above error

Comment: As of my experience, the Python shell is not a very good IDE. Try running a short script with `import pygame` and see if that gives an error. If yes, then you've not properly downloaded pygame.

Comment: Just because `import pygame` doesn't give an error doesn't mean pygame is installed properly.  After importing try `pygame.init()`.

Comment: thank, will try when back at computer:)

Comment: gave up with pygame on Python 3x. Got it up and running straight away in 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Using Pycharm. My python file was called pygame. When I copied and pasted the code into another python file with a different name, it worked. This is as new to me as anything.